# PyQt: making screenshots and QTimer

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

This a beginner's question so I truly apologize for this (have never used Python before but have to modify an existing script asap).

I try to make screenshots for a number of web pages. It's been going well but I've noticed that I sometimes get duplicates even though links are different. It seems that one needs to use QTimer for this and a simple time out solution wouldn't work. I have previously had:

1) `Screenshot` class with the `capture` method that would take a web link as a parameter

2) one instance of `Screenshot` and call `capture(url)` multiple times while looping over a list of web links in main

Now that I have to use `QTimer` and all the examples I've seen so far put it in the `__init__`, which would be something like

```
    self.timerScreen = QTimer()
    self.timerScreen.setInterval(1000)
    self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
    self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.capture)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)
    self.load(QUrl(url))
```

I have to pass urls at initialization (`def __init__(self, urlLst, parent=None)` ) which makes me think that I'd rather collect all urls in advance and make one instance of Screenshot which I will also call only once. As a result, I should loop over urls in the initialization block and call capture there. Needless to say, I clearly fail to do it well and `capture` doesn't even get called. (I have also tried an alternative - to make one instance per link - but not much success there either). Any ideas as to how I could fix it? Thank you so much in advance!

```
class Screenshot(QWebView):
   def __init__(self, urlLst, webidLst, parent=None):
    super(Screenshot, self).__init__(parent)
    self.timerScreen = QTimer()
    self.timerScreen.setInterval(1000)
    self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
    for index, item in enumerate(urlLst):
        self.url = item
        self.webid = webidLst[index]
        self.output_file = self.webid + ".png"
        self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.capture)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)
        self.load(QUrl(self.url))

  def capture(self):
    frame = self.page().mainFrame()
    self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
    # render image
    image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    if image.isNull() is False:
        painter = QPainter(image)
        frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()
        print '\n for webid=' + str(self.webid) + '\t for web page=' + str(self.url)
        print ' saving ', self.output_file  
        image.save(self.output_file)

# In main:
# store all links in LinkLst and their ids in webpageidLst
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
s = Screenshot(linkLst, webpageidLst)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: did you manage it? I have the same issue